# How to change htdocs to different directory in XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp, server

How can i change the default root directory to custom

e.g from **xampp/htdocs** folder to **D:/Web projects**

I have already tried all the mention methods here and on alot of places none of them working it seems. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the xampp/conf/httpd.conf then change the 'DocumentRoot' to the new directory, also change the 'Directory' tag to the new directory then save the file and restart apache server.

Comment: i dono , this time it worked !. Thanks for being lucky charm :D

Answer (score 1):

Edit the httpd.conf file and change the line DocumentRoot so it should be D:/Web Projects

That should work.